# Youtube api, how do i set part 'q'?

Tags: html, json, youtube-api

Basicly i want the part 'q' to be known. So the Json code says the reason is unknown because if i understood correctly ive put the part: 'q'. So my question is how do i make the part:'q' known i think im supposed to use some keyword but i dont know how i should call it? I put it some html that might be able to search for the keyword but it may be wrong...

(new at JSON and Youtube Api)

sorry for bad eng and explanation.

Here's my code:

```
<div id = "searchBar">
<form  id="yt-search" action="" method="get" target="_self">
<input id="yt-search-term" name="search_query" type="text" maxlength="128" />
<select name="search_type" id="search_type"> 
 <option value="" >Videos</option>
 <option value="search_users">Channels</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="search" />
</form>
</div>



function googleApiClientReady() {

var apiKey = 'x';

gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {

    request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        part: 'q',
        part: 'contentDetails',
        order: 'date',
        type: 'video'

    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
            console.log(response);

    });
});
}
```

JSON answer:

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "youtube.part",
"reason": "unknownPart",
"message": "contentDetails",
"locationType": "parameter",
"location": "part"
}],
"code": 400,
"message": "contentDetails"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the resource `contentDetails` is unknown because it's not a valid parameter of `part`, only `snippet` works

> part  string The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of
>   one or more search resource properties that the API response will
>   include. Set the parameter value to snippet.

Check all the parameters https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters

Your request should look like this :

```
function googleApiClientReady() {

var apiKey = 'x';

gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {

    request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: 'fishing',
        order: 'date',
        type: 'video'

    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
            console.log(response);

    });
});
}
```

Comment: What is the correct format for submitting a keyword phrase? **ie:**  `fishing boats`, `'fishing boats'`, `fishing+boats`, or `fishing%20boats`?